# Home button for wake sleep

Tags: buttons, standby, samsung-droid-charge

Using Verizon Samsung Droid Charge how can I wake the phone using the home button instead of just the side power button? (My phone is rooted.)

Answer (score 1):

well, in my opinion, you can use Cyanogenmod 7 ROM. I have Cyanogenmod 7.0.3 and I can wake my phone using the home button. You can use the ROM Manager to install clockworkmod and download cyanogenmod 7 specific to your phone:
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&hl=en
Refer to the following guide for installing cyanogenmod 7:
http://www.redmondpie.com/install-cm7-on-galaxy-s2-using-rom-manager-how-to-tutorial/
The guide is for samsung galaxy s2 but its almost similar for all.

Best of luck!